# HTML and Plaintext email over Python through Zabbix

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, html-email, zabbix

I'm working on a script that creates both an HTML and Plaintext email. This didn't seem like a hassle, but I can't hardcode the e-mail into the script I'm using. Allow me to explain why.

I'm using the Zabbix Monitoring system to keep an eye out for my systems. Allow me to use a printer for example. Once one of the toners is close to dying, I want both an HTML and plain text mail to be sent. Zabbix uses several macros however, which can be used to identify what system is being affected by what.

So, the HTML body needs to received before the script is run. Once the HTML body has been received with the correct values, it needs to have a plain copy too. As much as I'd like to have the plain-text contain the correct parameters (copied from the macros) too, I don't consider this a necessity.

This is what my script currently looks like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

list1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

import mimetypes, os, smtplib, sys
from email import encoders
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

me = "x"
you = "y"
DESTINATION=sys.argv[1]
SUBJECT=sys.argv[2]
MESSAGE=sys.argv[3]
PASS='password'

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

text = "A problem has been detected on {HOST.NAME} \n \n Trigger: {TRIGGER.NAME} \n Status: {TRIGGER.STATUS} \n Severity: {TRIGGER.SEVERITY} "
#html = 


# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
#part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
#msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('mysmtpserver')
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()
s.login(me, PASS)
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

The reason why I can't have them being sent seperately or sending the HTML copy alone is because my e-mails get nuked by SpamAssassin. I'm intending to send certain error messages to my customers. So they are immediately notified when their toner is nearly empty, so they can place a new order. The HTML-email has been set up and has been working without failure.

So to put it onto perspective one more time.

- Zabbix recieves an error.
- There is a default HTML message written, macros become filled, this then needs to be imported to the script.
- The script is then run.
- There's an e-mail sent with both HTML content as well as the
  plain-text for users that can't read the HTML-emails.

The reason the script is a mess is because I've already tried several options, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Do you created a media type inside Zabbix?

Comment: Yes. The script is working, media type etc has been set up correctly. When I state Zabbix recieves an error, I mean from an external source. A trigger is activated. All I want to do is to be able to send both a HTML and plain-text e-mail. As for now, it's either of these two options, it can't be both.

Comment: Zabbix by default send email as plain text. You have to configure your 'Action' to send both.